# Unequal Filesize and Datatransfer on Website resources

Tags: html, web, firefox

I am making a website and I've noticed that the files like styles.css are getting pretty big.
But in the network analysis in firefox developer tools, the file size and the transfered data seem to be unequal and I have wondered why?
Is it unused css that's being stripped, or maybe compression?
I am using ModX cms, PHP-Fpm with Zend OPcache.

And also as I'm already here maybe someone can help me with this:
Why are my fonts loading twice, I do not have lazyload etc.
montserrat-regular.tff and fa-solid-900.woff2 alternately keep loading twice, unfortunately I can not share the real domain name, so I hope someone can still help me, even without looking at the real page.

```
@font-face {
        font-family: 'Montserrat';
        src: url('https://domain.online/manager/templates/default/fonts/montserrat-regular.ttf');
    }
```

[screenshot of webanalysis in firefox](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gnNTK.png)
Thank you for your time

Comment: firefox might be asking your webserver for gzip compression